# DI and inheritance

Tags: eclipse, inheritance, dependency-injection, eclipse-rcp, e4

Another question appeared during my migration from an E3 application to a pure E4.

I got a Structure using inheritance as in the following pic. 
[image]

There I have an invocation sequence going from the AbstractRootEditor to the FormRootEditor to the SashCompositeSubView to the TableSubView.
There I want to use my EMenuService, but it is null due to it can´t be injected.

The AbstractRootEditor is the only class connected to the Application Model (as a MPart created out of an MPartDescriptor).

I´d like to inject the EMenuService anyway in the AbstractSubView, otherwise I would´ve the need to carry the Service through all of my classes. But I don´t have an IEclipseContext there, due to my AbstractSubView is not connected with Application Model (Do I ?).

I there any chance to get the service injected in the AvstractSubView?

EDIT:
I noticed that injecting this in my AbstractSubView isn´t possible (?), so I´m trying to get it into my TableSubView.

After gregs comment i want to show some code: 
in the AbstractRootEditor:

```
    @PostConstruct
    public final void createPartControl(Composite parent, @Active MPart mPart) {
...
ContextInjectionFactory.make(TableSubView.class, mPart.getContext());
```

First I got an Exception, saying that my TableSubView.class got an invalid constructor, so now the Constructor there is:

```
public TableSubView() {
        this.tableInputController=null;
    }
```

as well as my Field-Injection:

```
@Inject EMenuService eMenuService
```

This is kind of not working, eMenuService is still null

Comment: Where are you testing for `eMenuService` being null? It will be null in the `TableSubView` constructor because field injection is not done until after construction.

Comment: Ah I forgot about everything beeing in the PostConstruct-Method.
Seems like I have to carry the MenuService through the classes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create your objects using `ContextInjectionFactory` they will be injected. Use:

```java
MyClass myClass = ContextInjectionFactory.make(MyClass.class, context);
```

where `context` is an `IEclipseContext` (so you have to do this for every class starting from one that is injected by Eclipse).

There is also a seconds version of `ContextInjectionFactory.make` which lets you provide two contexts the second one being a temporary context which can contain additional values.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I defined that in my AbstractRootEditor, making the context for the AbstractSubView .but i´m still unsure about which context is to set, due to i can´t select a context in the AbstractSubView

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the comment. Show us some actual code.

Comment: I edited my Post now, I firstly was curious about which context I should enter there, but the MApplication.getContext didn´t work, and it threw InjectionException: Unable to process "MenuService.myPart": no actual value was found for the argument "MPart".